# ZF2 doesnt return data from MSSQL

Tags: php, sql, pdo, zend-framework2

I am new to ZF2, and I got stuck with getting data from MSSQL Server.

Currently I can connect to MSSQL server with no problems, also I can execute "UPDATE" Queries and they work fine. But as soon as I want to get any data from database to display in my website problems begin..

```
public function indexAction()
{
   $dbAdapter = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('db');
   $rs =  $dbAdapter->query("SELECT * FROM Character")->execute();
    return new ViewModel(array('rowset' => $rs));  
}
```

this is my very primitve function to get data from SQL and passit to view template,

I try to display it :

```
<?php
    foreach ($rowset as $row) {
?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php  echo $row['AccountID']; ?></td>
            <td><?php  echo $row['Name']; ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
```

and I get `Fatal error: Invalid sql_display_size in .... zendframework\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Result.php on line 157`

As I said, if I try to run UPDATE Query it works with no problems and data is updated in the MSSQL..

Thanks.

Comment: is the error in the view, in `query()`, or in `execute()`?

Comment: no errors in the functions, sql statement is very simple